# Maintain (or restore) file permissions when replacing file

Tags: bash, permissions, files, scripting

I have a command that accepts a file as an argument, modifies the file, then writes it to the file name specified in the second argument.   I'll call that program `modifyfile`.

I wanted it to work "in place" so I wrote a shell script (bash) that modifies it to a temporary file then moves it back:

```
TMP=`mktemp`
modifyfile "$original" "$TMP"
mv -v "$TMP" "$original"
```

This has the unfortunate side effect of destroying the permissions on this file.  The file gets re-created with default permissions.

Is there a way to tell the `mv` command to overwrite the destination without altering its permissions?  Or alternately is there a way to save the user, group, and permisssions from the original and restore them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of using `mv`, just redirect `cat`. For example:

```
TMP=$(mktemp)
modifyfile "$original" "$TMP"
cat "$TMP" > "$original"
```

This overwrites `$original` with the contents of `$TMP`, without touching anything at the file level.

Comment: Couldn't that be problematic if some program has an open file handle to the file?

Comment: I then have to `rm "$TMP"` as well, but it seems to do just what I want.

Comment: @MartinvonWittich it would probably be a problem if you were using `mv` instead. I don't see a way to solve that problem.

Comment: @MartinvonWittich Yes. Create-new-then-move gives you an atomic change and doesn't affect programs that have the file open, but since it creates a new file the file's ownership and permissions are lost. Truncate-existing-then-write preserves permissions and ownership but loses data in case of a crash and swipes the rug under the feet of programs that have the file open. You can't combine the good parts of both.

Comment: @Gilles: how about transferring the ownership and permissions with `ch{own,mod} --reference="$TMP"` before using `mv`? There are probably some more attributes to consider (ACLs? EAs? chattr?), but it seems like good solution to me.

Comment: @MartinvonWittich `chown` only works as root. `chmod` and `chgrp` may or may not work depending on the user's permissions. Neither copies other attributes such as ACL or filesystem-specific extended attributes.

Answer (score 10):

There are two strategies to replace a file by a new version:

1. Create a temporary file with the new version, then move it into place.

   - Advantage: if a program opens that file, it will either read the old content or the new content, depending on whether it opened the file before or after the move. There is no mix-up.
   - Advantage: in case of a crash, the old content is preserved.
   - Downside: since a new file gets created, the file's attributes (ownership, permission, etc.) are not preserved.
2. Overwrite the old file in place.

   - Advantage: the file's attributes are preserved.
   - Downside: in case of a crash, the file may be left half-written.
   - Downside: if a program has the file open when it is being updated, this program may read inconsistent data.

If you can, use method 1, but first replicate the attributes of the original file with `cp -p --attributes-only`. This requires GNU coreutils (i.e. non-embedded Linux, or sufficiently Linux-like environments). If your `cp` doesn't have `--attributes-only`, omit this option: it'll work but it'll replicate the data as well.

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
cp -p --attributes-only "$original" "$tmp"
modifyfile "$original" "$tmp"
mv -f "$tmp" "$original"
```

If you cannot replicate the attributes of the existing file, for example because you have write permissions on it but do not own it and you want to preserve the owner, then only method 2 is possible. To minimize the risk of data loss:

- Make the window during which the file will be incomplete as small as possible. Prepare the data first in a temporary file, then copy it into place.
- Make a backup of the old file first.

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
backup="${original}~"
modifyfile "$original" "$tmp"
cp -p "$original" "$backup"
cp -f "$tmp" "$original"
```

Comment: Nice answer! Nowadays I'd suggest using the argument *--attributes-only* with _cp_ command in *Method 1*. In this way, the `cp -p --attributes-only "$original" "$tmp"` will not use resources to copy the contents of the file. I couldn't find from which version this argument was added.

Comment: @MarceloBarros It was added in GNU coreutils 8.6 released 2010-10-15, so these days if you have GNU coreutils you should have it. There's still no such thing with other `cp` implementations.

Answer (score 5):

After our discussion on the first answer, I propose a different answer:

```
TMP="$(mktemp "$original".XXXXXXXXXX)"
modifyfile "$original" "$TMP"
chmod --reference="$original" "$TMP"
chown --reference="$original" "$TMP"
mv -f "$TMP" "$original"
```

Remarks:

- I use `$original` in the `mktemp` template to ensure that the temporary file is not placed in `/tmp` but in the same folder as `$original`. I believe that if `/tmp` is mounted on a different filesystem the operation would no longer be atomic.
- The result of `mktemp` is now quoted in case it contains whitespace.
- I use `$()` instead of `` because I consider it cleaner.
- `ch{mod,own} --reference` are used to transfer the permissions of `$original` to `$TMP`. If someone has additional ideas what metadata can and should be transferred, then please edit my post and add it.
- Oh well, this requires root permissions as Gilles pointed out. Well, I'm not going to discard this now that I've written it :P